# How can I delay the execution time of a php script, so the python script can finish

Tags: php, python, neural-network

I have a script in php that is calling a python one, which is a neural network being trained and it takes about 80 seconds to finish, but my php script finishes fast.

I tried just creating a csv file in python which is a quick process, and it worked, so its really a question of time.

I've already tried using the following code, and it didn't worked.

```
var_dump(time_sleep_until(microtime(true)+100));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Symphony Process component -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

It allows you to run processes asynchronously and check whether they are still running: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the manual

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

```
sleep ( int $seconds ) : int
```

Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.

**Parameters ¶**

seconds
Halt time in seconds.

**Return Values ¶**

Returns zero on success, or FALSE on error.

If the call was interrupted by a signal, sleep() returns a non-zero value. On Windows, this value will always be 192 (the value of the WAIT_IO_COMPLETION constant within the Windows API). On other platforms, the return value will be the number of seconds left to sleep.

**Errors/Exceptions ¶**

If the specified number of seconds is negative, this function will generate a E_WARNING.

Answer (score 0):

[`usleep(100);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) is more intuitive for what you are trying to do than using time_sleep_until, although I believe your time_sleep_until should work pretty similarly. However, the [manual for time_sleep_until()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php#refsect1-function.time-sleep-until-examples) seems to suggest that it may not work consistently for short times (such as .2 seconds). I would try usleep instead.